# WP7 ListPicker on Popup causing Back button problems

Tags: windows-phone-7, toolkit

I am using the WP7 Tookit ListPicker (Feb release) on a Popup Control. I have trapped the Back button so I can close the popup.

If I press the back button while the ListPicker is open in popup mode, my back button event handler is firing before the ListPicker handles it so both the ListPicker and my popup are closing.

One way I thought of handling it was to check and see if I have any ListPickers on the popup that are open and if so close the and cancel the navigation (the controls on my popup are added dynamically so I have to enumerate through the popup child controls to check) but I can't find a way of seeing if the ListPicker is Open or Closing it.

So my question is a) is there a way of handling this in the back button handler and if not b) how can I check if a ListPicker is Open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your popup control's `BackKeyPress` callback add the following check:

```
if( myListPicker.ListPickerMode == ListPickerMode.Normal ) {
  // Close popup

  // Cancel navigation
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```

When `ListPickerMode` is `Expanded` or `Full` the `ListPicker` will catch the back key pressed event and close itself.

**EDIT:**

According to @SteveChadbourne's comment the following worked:

```
if( myListPicker.ListPickerMode != ListPickerMode.Normal ) {
  // Close the ListPicker
  myListPicker.ListPickerMode = ListPickerMode.Normal;

  // Cancel navigation
  e.Cancel = true;

}
```

Comment: Tried setting the ListPicker to Full and it did not catch the back key press before the popup. Checking the ListPickerMode does not tell me if the ListPicker is open or not. Also need to know how to Close if Open.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: What do you mean by "ListPickerMode does not tell me if the ListPicker is open or not"?. ListPickerMode is set to `Expanded` when the ListPicker shows multiple items in place, and it is set to `Full` when the ListPicker is in fullscreen mode. To close the ListPicker just set ListPickerMode to `Normal`, but you don't have to do this if you use the code above and just ignore the back key press if ListPickerMode is anything other than Normal. The ListPicker automatically closes when in Expanded or Full mode and the back key is pressed.

Comment: I completely got the wrong end of the stick on what ListPickerMode does. Thought it was set to reflect behavior eg set to Full to always show popup. What it actually does is reflect state. My problem is not fixed by ignoring if not Normal as if Full the parent popup is closed before the ListPicker. Have trapped if Full and set to Normal with a cancelled navigation and all works. Cheers.

Comment: can you change the answer above as it does not actually fix the problem. Need to check for ListPickerMode != ListPickerMode.Normal then set to Normal and cancel navigation. Have tested and neither Expanded or Full trap the back key before a parent popup. Both work fine on a normal page. I can then mark it as the answer.